# If a control's "visible" property is set to "False" do any of its events fire?

Tags: asp.net, events, event-handling, lifecycle, web-controls

I have a GridView that has its `RowDataBound` event set.

If I change the GridView's "Visible" property to "False" during a postback caused by another control's event (a button's `OnClick` event for example), will the GridView's events still fire?

Looking at [ASP.NET Page Life Cycle Overview](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) I can't determine if this would be the case or not since the documentation simply states that `Control Events` occur after the `Load` event and before the `LoadComplete` event, but no order is given that I can see and no indication on whether or not the "Visible" property would change it's execution of events.

I would assume, though possibly incorrectly, that when an event causes a postback, that the event that caused the postback would execute first and then subsequent control events would follow in no particular order. If a control's event changes a "Visible" property to "True" for another control that was "False" prior to the postback, the control that became visible would "catch-up" with it's events firing before the cycle moved on to the `LoadComplete` page event.

I would also assume that if a control's "Visible" property is set to "False" during any events prior to `Control Events` occurring in the life cycle (`PreInit`, `Init`, `InitComplete`, `PreLoad` and `Load`) that those control's events would not execute.

Is this correct? I can't seem to find any official documentation that confirms this or not.

Answer (score 1):

Visible property value don't affect the sequence of events that happen in a page and the controls inside. *Only catch is that the Render events for the control wont be called in case Visible is set to false for that control.* 
It doesn't matter at what event in the life cycle the value is set.

Sequence is:

1. Init - from child control to the parent control.(Init of child
   control fires first and Init of the Page fires the last)
2. Load - from the parent control to the child control.
3. Render - from the parent control to the child control.
4. Unload - from the child control to the parent control.

To reiterate there is no sequence change in firing of events by changing the value of *Visible* property for a control. Also there is no *catch-up* concept here that happens while adding dynamic controls.